# Facebook Application Error: https://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I am new in developing my facebook application. I know php, HTML. I have a application in my server: http://www.example.com/app_name
with only one file written in php i,e index.php

I filled all the requisite as instructed by facebook documentation for canvas URL and all. Now when i am trying to access this http://apps.facebook.com/app_name

I get this error: The Page you requested was not found.
https://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php

Can anyone please help me????

Comment: Voting to close as this is too localised - this is a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325223977546904 and will likely be fixed shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a currently open bug report in Facebook's bug tracker about this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325223977546904

Answer (score 0):

It could take a while for your app to propagate to all FB servers so you may just have to wait a little. Are you logged in as the administrator to the app? If you have it set to private then you will be redirected to the 404 page if you are not an admin or tester.

Comment: Good answer, but right now (May 1st 2012) there's an active bug regarding this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325223977546904

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which seemed to be transitory. About ten minutes later the site started working again. Facebook.... Sigh.